# How to execute a script at shutdown of a launch process

Tags: roslaunch

I am trying to execute a bash script when my robotic simulation is shut down (to tear down the network configuration necessary for the simulation).

I use ROS2 launch system to do so and I planned on using the `OnShutdown` event handler to launch some ROS actions when I ctrl-C the launch system.

However, I fail to execute anything else than a `LogInfo` action in this callback:

Example launch file:

```py
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, LogInfo, RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnShutdown
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LocalSubstitution

def generate_launch_description():

    talker_node = Node(
            package='demo_nodes_cpp',
            executable='talker',
            name='demo_talker',
        )

    ld = LaunchDescription([
        talker_node,
        RegisterEventHandler(
            OnShutdown(
                on_shutdown=[
                    LogInfo(
                        msg=['Launch was asked to shutdown: ', LocalSubstitution('event.reason')]
                    ),
                    ExecuteProcess(
                        cmd=['echo', 'Hello from ExecuteProcess']
                    )
                ]
            )
        )
    ])

    return ld
```

This will give the following output. It ignores the `echo` command entirely, but executes `LogInfo` properly.

```sh
theotime@theotime-Precision-5570:~/simulation_ws$ ros2 launch src/launch/test_launch.py --show-all-subprocesses-output 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/theotime/.ros/log/2023-06-20-15-25-59-974180-theotime-Precision-5570-170652
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [talker-1]: process started with pid [170653]
[talker-1] [INFO] [1687267561.062017969] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[talker-1] [INFO] [1687267562.061961754] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[talker-1] [INFO] [1687267563.061974971] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[INFO] [launch.user]: Launch was asked to shutdown: ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[talker-1] [INFO] [1687267563.397639727] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [talker-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 170653]
```

Why does `OnShutdown` refuse to execute actions other than `LogInfo`?

How can I execute a bash script on shutdown of a launch process ?

For reference and convenience: [Link to the code responsible for `OnShutdown`](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/rolling/launch/launch/event_handlers/on_shutdown.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this. I don't have advice about the root cause, but it looks like you can provide a callable to the `on_shutdown=` argument which might work for your use case.

For example, I can define:

```py
def shutdown_func_with_echo_side_effect(event, context):
    os.system('echo [os.system()] Shutdown callback function can echo this way.')
    return [
        LogInfo(msg='Shutdown callback was called for reason "{}"'.format(event.reason)),
        ExecuteProcess(cmd=['echo', 'However, this echo will fail.'])]
```

and register it with the `OnShutdown` event handler like this:

```py
ld = LaunchDescription([
        talker_node,
        RegisterEventHandler(
            OnShutdown(on_shutdown=shutdown_func_with_echo_side_effect)
        )
    ])
```

This gives

```
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below <path to logs>
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [talker.EXE-1]: process started with pid [19092]
[talker.EXE-1] [INFO] [1687924816.372554600] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 1'
[talker.EXE-1] [INFO] [1687924817.377274200] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 2'
[talker.EXE-1] [INFO] [1687924818.367993100] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 3'
[talker.EXE-1] [INFO] [1687924819.381295400] [demo_talker]: Publishing: 'Hello World: 4'
[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[os.system()] Shutdown callback function can echo this way.
[INFO] [launch.user]: Shutdown callback was called for reason "ctrl-c (SIGINT)"
[INFO] [talker.EXE-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 19092]
```

Like your example, the `ExecuteProcess` action returned by the function does not appear to do anything.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the workaround !
I still think this hides a flaw in the ROS Launch system, especially since no error/warning message is shown.

Comment: Agreed. This may be relevant: https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/684, although I guess that's specific to `launch_pytest`.